# Stack Overflow taking down the evil Hyphen Site

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, experts-exchange

From [The Hyphen Site being taken down by Stack Overflow; they've crossed the line.](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/9884m/expertsexchange_being_taken_down_by_stackoverflow/), [Alexa](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com+experts-exchange.com) and [Google Trends](http://trends.google.com/websites?q=stackoverflow.com,+experts-exchange.com).

Man I would love to see some statistics on questions and answers on the evil hyphen site (as Joel calls it) since Stack Overflow came onto the scene.

Answer (score 11):

You can register for [free at Experts-Exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/registerFree2.jsp). It only costs you to ask questions if you haven't already answered some. And once you've answered a few, you get a very low-bandwidth view of it too.

I'm not saying the site is brilliant, but I don't think it deserves quite the bad press that it gets.

Comment: Sure it does. That hidden solution is horrible.

Comment: But if you regsiter (for free), then you can see all the answers anyway. Personally, I'd rather see SO/SF trying to help EE, and also the MS Forums, and the same for all the other community sites. At the end of the day, we're all trying to provide a service to the community, right?

Comment: At the end of the day, Jeff, Jared, and Geoff need to eat.  (i.e.) They need to make money.

Comment: The way I see it is... they need money to be able to pay for the site to run. Many years ago they had people stealing content from the site, driving down their ability to stay up, so they made it 'registered members only'. But then they had to make sure that the search robots needed to be able to see the content, so they came up with a less-than-ideal solution. But really they should just advertise the "register free" option beter. Maybe send your co-workers to http://www.experts-exchange.com/registerFree2.jsp, where they can register to see (and answer) questions there.

Comment: Don't have to now, i can link directly to answers on SO. Such things are good cause for jubilation... Come, brother, let us celebrate The Open Web!

Comment: experts-exchange gets to choose what face they show to the world.  The world's opinion of them is the result.

Answer (score 7):

Heh: [We're answering their questions](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24011629/Doubt-with-multiple-inheritance-and-virtual-base-classes-in-C.html).

([314 hits](http://www.google.co.nz/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=%2Bstackoverflow.com+site%3Aexperts-exchange.com&btnG=Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=))

You can't see the accepted solution if you follow a link directly to the page.  Anyway, the accepted solution is a [link to SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396327/question-on-multiple-inheritance-virtual-base-classes-and-object-size-in-c).

Comment: Wow, that's interesting cos yes normally the solution is at the bottom. They've done it that way so Google doesn't yank them for showing a search engine different content. It's an interesting twist that non-Google links don't display it though.

Comment: Yes, you only see the answers if the referer is Google, or you join the site.

Answer (score 7):

I've been an Experts Exchange member for about 9 years now. I haven't been very active there for a while, though. I lost a bit of interest in that site since my favorite topic (Delphi) has become less interesting and most questions have been asked before and thus repeat themselves. Still, I've never paid for this site and have earned four t-shirts and a $100 prize from them by answering a lot of other people's questions there. It also gave me enough points to ask a new question there every day for the next 5 years, if I want to.
Then, of course, membership of EE can be free if you earn enough points per month to be recognized as an expert. And to be honest, if they would make every member with over half a million points (like me) a permanent member, I would probably be more interested in EE and less in SO. It's just that I don't want to spend every day on EE trying to earn points so I'm a free member for just another month.

Comment: +1 *just another month* -> 2 months if you play it right.  I think you get the remainder of the month plus 1 month buffer.  But yeah, I remember having to earn the status every time I wanted to ask a question.

Answer (score 6):

I love SO, but I'm old enough to remember EE's first days.

At that time, the force was with them.

:-(

Answer (score 3):

I've signed up with experts-exchange.com when they used to increase the points constantly by time passing. Then I had 2000+ points when they closed down my account, and asking me to subscribe to their premium account.

viva la Stackoverflow.com!!

Comment: That shouldn't matter. Currently, I have just a regular account, not a premium account. Why? Didn't earn enough points lately. However, EE has two kinds of points. Points that you earn, which could pay for your premium account. And points that you can spend on new questions. You should still have both. I now have 589K expert points and 6771 question points. Won't run out of credit soon, I think...