# A StackOverflow milestone?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, traffic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stackoverflow taking down the evil Experts Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12989/stackoverflow-taking-down-the-evil-experts-exchange)

According to my query on [Alexa](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com+experts-exchange.com), this week the traffic to stackoverflow.com exceeded that to a competing knowledge exchange site with a hyphen in its name.

Comment: "... traffic to stackoverflow.com exceeded that to a competing knowledge exchange site with a hyphen in its name."  We finally surpassed ask-questions.com?  That's impressive, considering we don't have even one Q&A on home improvement.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12989/stackoverflow-taking-down-the-evil-experts-exchange

Answer (score 2):

Google trends for the two sites:

http://trends.google.com/websites?q=stackoverflow.com,+experts-exchange.com

Comment: That is beautiful.

Comment: What happened at the turn of the year? haha, everyone on break? EE saw that huge drop, but even SO experienced one.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder when other sites will respond to the competition?

Answer (score 0):

What's interesting to me is that the expert sex change thing is not in decline.  At worst, SO has merely eaten into their growth.

Comment: Not according to the graph in Espo's answer :)

Comment: Oh, wow!  I had not seen his answer.  Ouch.