# Does the Stack Overflow CEO really believe that arrogance is good and humility is bad?

Tags: discussion, company, ceo

In [an interview with Jyoti Bansal published on LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ceo-rapidfire-stack-overflow-prashanth-chandrasekar-talks-bansal/) on 13th June 2023, Stack Overflow CEO Prashanth Chandrasekar was asked:

> Your one “non-negotiable” in business (or life) is:

Prashanth's response:

> Lack of humility/arrogance.

This seems stunning, since I'm quite sure most of us consider that humility is good and arrogance is bad ─ the opposite of what Prashanth appears to say. On the other hand, there's nothing about the context to suggest his answer shouldn't be taken literally, and it's not unprecedented for executives to believe things like "greed is good" which are totally contrary to the values held by the rest of society.

I considered that perhaps his answer is just poorly phrased; maybe he means that "lack of humility/lack of arrogance" is non-negotiable for him. But I don't think this is a viable interpretation, because humility and arrogance are opposites ─ and the question asks for *one* non-negotiable thing ─ and it would still imply he thinks humility is bad. Alternatively, perhaps he thought the question actually meant something like *"what qualities make it impossible to negotiate with someone?"*, so he meant that he can't negotiate with people who lack humility or are arrogant. But I think that would require a pretty drastic misunderstanding of the question, particularly in context.

Does Prashanth stand by this statement, and if so, does the rest of Stack Exchange consider "lack of humility" and "arrogance" to be acceptable qualities in a leader?

Comment: It's a strange question to ask here because really only the CEO can answer it, but ... how many CEO's / high-ranking officials have you met? Every one I've met is overflowing with confidence and ambition. Perhaps those are just another way of describing lack of humility/arrogance.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk It could also be answered with references to other things Prashanth has said in public, and the question also addresses other SE staff, investors and associates. But I also don't think it is that unusual to ask for clarification on one specific thing that one person at SE has said.

Comment: To me this sounds like a misunderstanding. Nobody would ever say that even one who meant it. You don't need much to predict how that would be received. Probably he meant to say it the other way around (which doesn't necessarily makes it true just because you say it). Also I feel a bit as if this is a personal aspect of the CEO and not really about the software or community that empowers the network.

Comment: It's probably just a confusion with the use of double negatives, and he meant the opposite.

Comment: @interjay Perhaps, but it's amusing that President James K. Polk thinks it's unremarkable that the CEO would say this, while you think it's obvious that he meant the opposite. I think it's remarkable that he said it and not obvious that he didn't mean it, but if he did indeed not mean it then it would be easy to clear up.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I think "lack of humility" and "arrogance" are two ways of saying the same thing, and it doesn't make sense to list two opposite (and kind of contradictory) things as being one non-negotiable thing. So to me it reads fairly clearly as like "arrogance/lack of humility", not "lack of (humility/arrogance)".

Comment: A non-negotiable doesn't necessarily mean something you want. It might mean something that you cannot accept.

Comment: @khelwood I am not aware of such usage for the term "non-negotiable", and in every context I have seen it it means something you insist on, not something you insist on the opposite of. Do you have a reference which discusses the usage you're talking about?

Comment: @khelwood same, it's terribly confusing for non-native English speakers, or those not familiar with those terms from other places, but that's already LinkedIn fault for using confusing language.

Comment: This looks to be something that should be asked on LinkedIn, not here, as the question doesn't show how this might be relevant to the topic and scope of this site.

Comment: Honestly I'm surprised, there seem to be a bunch of people who object to this question on the basis that obviously he didn't mean that, and another bunch who object on the basis that it's unremarkable that he would say it and mean it. And neither camp seem to believe there is anything that needs to be clarified.

Comment: @kaya3-supportthestrike Just that the literal meaning of non-negotiable is something that cannot be negotiated. Reading it as "something *that I must have* that cannot be negotiated" is just assumption.

Comment: I find it very weird, though it could be an artifact of editing. Anything of the form _**Your one “non-negotiable” in business (or life) is:** "Noun"_ seems to me (even as a native English speaker) like "Noun" is the thing they cannot do without. It would be better phrased, if intended in the positive way people are parsing it, as "People shouldn't be arrogant" or "People should be humble". You know, an actual sentence explaining.

Comment: *"[Greed is good](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wD1ivql1870&t=4s)"*. [The original](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVxYOQS6ggk&t=42s) (of many?).

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum The "original" was a real speech by Ivan Boesky, who said *"I think greed is healthy. You can be greedy and still feel good about yourself."* But he was echoing Ayn Rand who wrote a whole book titled *The Virtue of Selfishness*.

Answer (score 15):

I genuinely don't believe that this phrase can be understood to mean anything other than "lack of humility"/ [rephrase of same meaning] "arrogance".

Prasanth is very clearly stating that their non-negotiable is "lack of humility", and then rephrasing that *same meaning* as "arrogance", which is a common use of the `/` in a sentence.

You don't have to agree with him or take him at his word, but I really don't think it's reasonable to read that line as you have, especially given that no sane person would publicly announce arrogance as a virtue (and I think this holds true even among "greedy C-suite execs", who are arguably all about altruistic appearances anyway).

Frankly, this post comes across to me like it could be written as a willful attempt to paint folks in a bad light with frivolous reasoning. I feel this is distracting and unhelpful to [the issues at hand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390106), where management has earned much *justified* flack already. I don't think we gain anything from unreasonable call outs like this.

---

Kaya3 rightly [pointed out to me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1303166) that the phrasing in the article is still *exceptionally* odd. Verbatim, [it's presented as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcB03.png):

> **Your one “non-negotiable” in business (or life) is:** Lack of humility/arrogance.

As written, this can be read very negatively, but I still find it *highly* unlikely that conveying "Prasanth values arrogance" was the goal, especially given that the article is nothing more than a puff piece.

This is speculation on my part without access to a transcript or recording of the interview, but it seems pretty reasonable to me that what was actually said was akin to "What's something you find non-negotiable in business or life?" "Lack of humility or arrogance is non-negotiable; people have to have that quality to succeed", then whoever copy-edited the article just did a poor job rendering the meaning.

Comment: I really cannot follow what you are saying here. Yes, "lack of humility" and "arrogance" have the same meaning, the word "arrogance" is a rephrasing of "lack of humility"... that is exactly how I read his statement. I'm not sure what different way you think I read it, and I don't see how you can reach the opposite conclusion by reading it in this way. The reading which you advocate for literally means that he is proposing arrogance, equivalently lack of humility, as something that is non-negotiable for him, i.e. something he insists on.

Comment: As for the idea that "no sane person would publicly announce arrogance as a virtue", I addressed this by noting that some people, especially company executives, publicly announce greed as a virtue; and it's also interesting that the first comment on the question *is* basically defending arrogance as a virtue, and it's on +6.

Comment: @kaya3 Hey, you know what, you're absolutely right on the first bit– the way the point is printed in the article is _supremely_ strange, which I completely missed originally. It basically frames itself as "what's something you find non-negotiable?": "lack of humility", which is exceptionally odd.

Comment: @kaya3 That said, however, I _still_ don't buy that it was intentionally presented to mean "Prashanth values arrogance", and I don't think that that view would be even remotely well-received by anyone, even in the business world. I'm almost certain the interview went something like "What's something that's non-negotiable to you?" "Lacking humility/ arrogance is non-negotiable; people must have that to succeed", and then whoever copy-edited the article just did a poor job rendering the meaning. The article is nothing more than a puff piece anyway; I genuinely don't think there's more to it.

Answer (score 6):

The literal meaning of non-negotiable is something that cannot be negotiated. Reading it as "something that *I must have* that cannot be negotiated" is just assumption. It might mean something that you cannot accept or cannot manage.

For example: "When trying to communicate with Stack Exchange Inc. I find their lack of humility non-negotiable."

The interview question as given is ambiguous.