# Stack Exchange Moderators in Strike: Please announce here when it is finally over

Tags: discussion, moderation-strike

I just want to get tagged or informed somehow when the moderation strike is over, since the website doesn't have any official info about it (*and it is hardly going to happen, as you could see on the comments to [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35858/909869)*).

Please don't take it as a personal attack, it's just about how it is already too hard to surf about the moderator strike in the currently available questions which are full of distracting text, comments, and updates (hard for non-native English speakers like me).

This one aims to keep it simple. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Well, the [Bursdon teachers' strike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burston_Strike_School) lasted from 1914 to 1939. Why would this be any shorter?

Comment: Its not just how long *this* strike lasts - but also setting conditions so we don't *need* protest actions to be heard. There's no point to a quick ending if it results in a situation where we need to strike again, or some other issue which hurts the community that is avoidable.

Comment: Do strikes occur with premeditated timeline? There are the writers Guild strike and actors strike ongoing, for instance, so did they tell when those would be over? Any strike would end when a sustainable amicable consensus and demands have been met.

Comment: @tripleee actually it would make much more sense to update [the official strike announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an?noredirect=1&lq=1) and anyone who wants to keep track can just check it for new answers or edits.

Comment: or maybe close this as a dupe to that...

Comment: You can also follow [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390704/1333002) for updates on the strike

Comment: Note that it's not just a "moderator's strike". It's a moderat*ion* strike, meaning normal users (over a thousand) are involved as well. Personally, I'm not answering questions, or editing or flagging posts on SO (I still vote for tracking purposes). I'll go back to contributing when the strike is over, which I assume will happen when the striker's demands are met, mainly SE reallowing banning users for breaking LLM rules. I'm fully prepared for the company to never implement the necessary changes since all signs indicate they value robots over humans, based on their recent actions.

Comment: For those who wonder about the downvotes, I'll make exception and explain my own: the vibe from this post is "Stop striking, I want answers", and I don't really like that vibe.

Comment: @tripleee Thank you very much for your consideration. Some have taken really bad this question, but they should understand that for low level users is really weird what is happening and we don't really know how this site and the several other related sites work. I came to Meta just after the strike started and the posts and answers are really long, which is also hard for someone is not native in english. This is why a simpler question with a simple topic will help me and others to figure out what is happening.

Comment: I'm the user that left the first comment. I get what it's like, I remember what was happening when I joined 9 years ago and it baffled me for quite a while, but you get uesd to it. Behind my comment was my own uncertainty about what's going to happen. SE has gone through many changes, and the advent of AI tools for people to post spam or low quality stuff is new. The response so far has polarised the company and the moderators/curators in different directions. Poor communication, dishonest dealing and bad-mouthing in the press by the company..... Who knows what willl happen.

Comment: Personally, I feel as if there's a whole lot we're not being told about what's going on, and hearsay and strong emotional reactions may have coloured what we have heard to mask the facts. We'll just have to wait and see what happens. This AI thing is new to humanity, could be a great help, could go the other way - or a bt of both. Wait and see.

Comment: My expectation is that when the strike is resolved, there will be an official statement explaining what was agreed upon here on meta. It would be very unusual if it wasn’t a “featured” post. The announcement should show up on the right side of the page on any SE site (or at the bottom if you are on a small screen like a phone).

Comment: I tried to edit this into shape for possible reopening, but your subsequent edits have pretty much wrecked this question. I am retracting my vote to reopen.

Comment: @tripleee If was depending on me... I would erase everything after the first quote in dark. Shorter is better in my opinion, by many take it as a personal attack (which is not), and how previously stated don't fully got the idea to make it simple, now it does not neither unfortunately.

Comment: @tripleee I realize it do depend on me so I cut everything. Now if people don't like it is is out of my hands. Thanks for your efforts anyway, I appreciate it.

Comment: With the latest changes, I'll reinstate my promise to post an answer here when the strike is over, provided it doesn't get closed again as unclear or etc.

Comment: @tripleee If this question doesn't get an upvoted answer, it may be deleted by the roomba before the strike is over. https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/auto-deleted-questions

Comment: @ColleenV I have followed your recommendation adding a waste-answer hoping to avoid the issue you mentioned.

Comment: I didn’t make any recommendation, I simply pointed out a potential problem with @triplee’s promise to post an answer. My recommendation would be to glance at the sidebar every so often and wait for an official announcement. Hopefully that announcement will be written clearly enough that it won’t be difficult for EFL folks to understand.

Comment: There is some progress in the negotiations: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391847/273494

Comment: @ColleenV In [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390704/1210263) is stated that negotiations have concluded... It is going to be now like a poll among moderators in order to stop the strike or not?

Comment: **The strike is [officially over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392032/1345677).**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some [conclusions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391847/moderation-strike-results-of-negotiations?noredirect=1&lq=1) have been reached in negotiations; some users who are on strike, including myself, are now resuming activity.

Answer (score 3):

While there are still users who may decide to individually abstain from participating on the network going forward as a continuation of the strike, the strike is over.